# jQuery - Click sub element but hightlight parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="curent"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a>
        <ul class="sub">
           <li><a href="samsung.html">Samsung</a></li>
           <li><a href="lenovo.html">Lenovo</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="catalog_grid.html">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/5795/70a.png

I want to click any a tag and li tag parent is hightlighted. I try this code but it doesn't work with a tag in ul has sub class:

```
var this_url = window.location.href;

$('#block_nav_primary ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().attr('href') == this_url) {
        $('#block_nav_primary ul').find('li[class="curent"]').removeClass('curent');
        $(this).addClass('curent');
    }
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks for your help!

P/S: it looks like this thread [Highlight Parent Link in Navigation Menu With Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303645/highlight-parent-link-in-navigation-menu-with-jquery?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("ul a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("blue");
});
```

or

```
$("ul a").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("ul").addClass("blue");
});
```

CSS in both cases:

```
.blue > a {
   color: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edMBs/6/) to a quite similar scenario.

Comment: Why `parent().parent()`? Also `parents("ul")` will grab ALL parents with tag `<ul>`, hence `.closest("ul")` should be used instead. Anyway, the OP wants to highlight parent `<li>` element and not `<ul>`, as far as I see.

Comment: I agree on closest, however I thought il's parent is the target... I mean "li tag parent is hightlighted" is the `li` tag, that is the parent of the `a` or the parent of the `li`? :) Either way this code will do almost the request thing...

Comment: @BalintBako You are right! I tried closet, parent ... etc but there is  nothing work.

Comment: This is something like you want: http://jsfiddle.net/GCVAQ/4/ Not exactly the same, but quite close...

Comment: @BalintBako That's right but I don't want to hightlight LastLevel. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry wrong URL was the previous, however this is exactly what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/edMBs/3/

Comment: Can you hightlight FirstLevel?

Comment: But when I change .blue { color: blue; }, FirstLevel and LastLevel is blue. How to change color text FirstLevel?

Comment: LastLevel inherits the blue color, you need to specify the color for child elements or have a more selective css. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/edMBs/6/

Comment: @BalintBako Thanks so much! Do you see the picture and html code? Not only LastLevel can click and FirstLevel changes color, SecondLevel too. P/S: I gotta go, see you later.

Comment: I can, but you can also combine/enhance the examples I showed to select any element you want and you can change any css attribute on them :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understand your wording, but you want to apply the same effect to all LI tags, including those in a sublist?

Replace this:

```
$('#block_nav_primary ul li').each(function() {
```

With this:

```
$('#block_nav_primary ul').find('li').each(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
val items = $('#block_nav_primary ul li').click(function(){
    items.filter('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try styling it such that the `A` tag takes the width of the entire `LI` tag and so when you click `A` tag, it would highlight the entire thing. The CSS code for it would be something like:

```
li a {display: block; width: 100%; padding: 10px 0; background-color: pink;}
li a:hover {background-color: orange;}
```