# jQuery - How to select all element with <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="curent"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a>
        <ul class="sub">
           <li><a href="samsung.html">Samsung</a></li>
           <li><a href="lenovo.html">Lenovo</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="catalog_grid.html">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to select all element with anchor tag in code above, it means that when I click any  link `<a>`, then the parent **`<li>`** will be highlighted. How should I do?

P/S: if I have a menu like this, I can easy highlight li element:

```
 <ul>
     <li class="curent"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="products.html">Products</a>
     <li><a href="catalog_grid.html">News</a></li>
 </ul>

var this_url = window.location.href;

$('#block_nav_primary ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().attr('href') == this_url) {
        $('#block_nav_primary ul').find('li[class="curent"]').removeClass('curent');
        $(this).addClass('curent');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. I'm assuming you had some trouble with the formatting and that the asterisks shouldn't actually be displayed, but making "li" bold?

Comment: This question (especially the title) is confusing. If you want to select all elements with a tag, use just the tag name (like in a CSS selector): `$('li')`.

Comment: You shouldn't care about astericks, I use it to mark li(s) need to be highlighted. Of course, browser can't display it.

Answer (score 1):

### Update: to select the whole UL

You mean like this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/YrBMn/1/?

But what the asterisks li is for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
        $(this).siblings('ul').children('li').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi. My question looks like this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303645/highlight-parent-link-in-navigation-menu-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Just in case you have more nested html than just the anchor being an immediate child of the li then you should use $(this).closest('li') instead of $(this).parent('li') if you need to traverse up the tree.

Comment: Maybe I can't do it. Sorry if this article bothers you. I searched on internet but i can see anything can do like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example. Here is link http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/create-the-fanciest-dropdown-menu-you-ever-saw, you can click adobe -> dreamewaver or anything element in menu and this parent element will be highlighted. I wanna do this.